# Setting table layout through Java dynamically

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-tablelayout

I need my screen to have a couple of text views defined in the activity layout. Below those views I want to set a table whose number of rows and columns will depend upon the user's input (dynamic).

This code is in the oncreate of the activity

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    TableRow tableRow;
    TextView textView;

    for (int i = 0; i < no_days; i++) {
        tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        for (int j = 0; j < no_subjects; j++) {
            textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText("Hello");
            textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            tableRow.addView(textView);
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }

    setContentView(tableLayout);
```

But this code is taking the whole screen and I am unable to have those text views which I have defined in the activity layout.

Here's my activity_home_page.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.attendancerecord.HomePage"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your activity_home_page

Comment: Yes  activity_home_page.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want your `TableLayout` to below your `TextViews` then use `LinearLayout` with orientation "`vertical`" in `activity_home_page` instead of `RelativeLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.attendancerecord.HomePage"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display_user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And add `mainLinear.addView(tableLayout);` at the end of your loop

```
LinearLayout  mainLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView.setText("Hello");
                textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                tableRow.addView(textView);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        }
        mainLinear.addView(tableLayout);
```

And remove    `setContentView(tableLayout);`

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity file:

```
<TableLayout
     android:id="@+id/table1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/display_user_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

</TableLayout>
```

And in your class :

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table1);
         TableRow tableRow;
         TextView textView;
            for (int i = 0; i < no_days; i++) {
                tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                for (int j = 0; j < no_subjects; j++) {
                    textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    textView.setText("Hello");
                    textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                    tableRow.addView(textView);
                }
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
            }
```